# Architecture concept: Database driven web file management system

Tags: python, django, architecture

I want to develop a small file management system in Django Python. But my question doesn't bound to Python developers. This system will be able to do following functions:

- Create, Delete Folders
- Upload, Create, Copy, Move Files.

So the idea came in my mind is, put the path of files and folder in database. Physically I will save files in a directory but folders will have virtual existence. Unlike OS windows where every folder exist physically. So I have created two tables for demo:

**Table 1: Document Type**

```
class DocumentType(models.Model):
    id = models.IntegerField(primary_key=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200) #(File,Folder)
```

**Table 2: Documents**

```
class Documents(models.Model):
    file = models.FileField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    type = models.ForeignKey(DocumentType)
    parent = models.ForeignKey('self')
```

**Field "parent" role in documents table:**

It will be used for file to get info about the folder e.g file = abc.tx and parent = "myfiles". If parent field is empty or null then the file belongs to root folder.

> /myfiles/abc.txt

For folder it will be used for locating parent folder e.g name="fun" and parent ="images"

> /images/fun

**Web page functionality:**

On the page load I will populate folders type record. When user click on any folder then all files related to folder will be populated.

So my question is, Is this a good approach? either I need to create folders physically?

This is not a public application so I don't need to worry about permissions, sharing etc.

Please suggest me good way to do this.

Thank you

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want to build a virtual filesystem managed via the web. Since it seems to be acceptable to you to save the files in a "root" folder (i.e. on top of an existing filesystem), I'd build a file-management application that, without any abstraction, maps the files and directories to real ones under "root". Basically you end up with your own little [webmin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webmin).

Comment: Why use a relationnal database (very bad at handling trees) as a filesystem mock when you already have a filesystem ?

Comment: I have just create a demo DB design for clear the things.